# Pandas : Find last non-null value for each different value of a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
    a1  l1
0   a   NaN
1   a   kl
2   a   NaN
3   a   NaN
4   a   er
5   b   ye
6   b   NaN
7   b   fk
8   b   NaN
```

What I want is, the last previous non-null value of l1 for each group of a1 values. So the expected output is:

```
    a1  l1  ex
0   a   NaN NaN
1   a   kl  NaN
2   a   NaN kl
3   a   NaN kl
4   a   er  kl
5   b   ye  NaN
6   b   NaN ye
7   b   fk  ye
8   b   NaN fk
```

I have tried to use shift but I don´t know how to skip missing values.

Comment: No time to test this, but maybe try using `.pivot_table()` to get your data into a shape with a series (column) per group, then use `.fillna(method = 'ffill')` to propagate the values forward, the use `shift()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need `groupby` and `apply` here:

```
df['ex'] = df.groupby('a1').l1.apply(lambda x: x.ffill().shift())
df

  a1   l1   ex
0  a  NaN  NaN
1  a   kl  NaN
2  a  NaN   kl
3  a  NaN   kl
4  a   er   kl
5  b   ye  NaN
6  b  NaN   ye
7  b   fk   ye
8  b  NaN   fk
```

Alternatively, chain two `groupby` calls in succession:

```
df['ex'] = df.groupby('a1').ffill().groupby('a1').shift()
df

  a1   l1   ex
0  a  NaN  NaN
1  a   kl  NaN
2  a  NaN   kl
3  a  NaN   kl
4  a   er   kl
5  b   ye  NaN
6  b  NaN   ye
7  b   fk   ye
8  b  NaN   fk
```